# Drawing artefact with a NSBackgroundStyleRaised text field when the parent view draws a gradient

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Here is a NSView subclass that simply draws a subtle blue gradient (it's hard to see in this image but it is there) in it's bounds. Inside the view I place an NSTextField and set the cell to have NSBackgroundStyleRaised. The artefact is the background of the text field is draws with what looks like the same colour as it's superview. In this case the superview draws a gradient things look strange.

[image: View with gradient.]

The `-drawRect:` for the blue view is,

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Base colours
    baseColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.271 green: 0.578 blue: 0.874 alpha: 1];
    baseColorDarkened = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.159 green: 0.491 blue: 0.911 alpha: 1];

    // Draw gradient
    NSGradient* gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:baseColor  endingColor:baseColorDarkened];
    NSBezierPath* rectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect];
    [gradient drawInBezierPath: rectanglePath angle: 90];

    // Draw thin border
    NSBezierPath *border = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [[baseColorDarkened blendedColorWithFraction:0.2 ofColor:[NSColor blackColor]] set];
    [border setLineWidth:1];
    [border stroke];
}
```

I'm using a document based application so in `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` I set the properties of the text field,

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    [[_label1 cell] setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLowered];
    [_label1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]; // <-- Doesn't help :(
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some background styles seem to require special compositing (probably due to the shadows?).
OS X uses a cached & scaled representation of the superviews background when drawing the `NSTextField`.
I used your drawing code but changed the top color to make the cached drawing more apparent:

[image]

I found 2 workarounds:

- Simply enable layer backing on the superview of the label.
- When you can't enable layer backing, you could enforce a re-display of the label's superview. e.g. in the `NSWindowDelegate` method `windowDidUpdate:`

The second approach feels a bit hacky though:

```
- (void)windowDidUpdate:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   [self.label.superview setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! Even simpler, you can just make the text field layer backed in IB; that seems to work too. The other thing that worked was to draw the full rect of the view rather than just the `dirtyRect` every time. These tricks must tweak the redrawing order or something.

Comment: Actually I'm getting inconsistent results with making the text field layer backed, about 1/4 of the time is doesn't render correctly.

Comment: Setting layer backing on the textfield directly, doesn't work for me. Enabling it on the superview works consistently here.